# String numbers only and characters only

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, methods

I have ContactDTO class,
private ContactType contacttype;(this is enum, EMAIL, PHONENUMBEr)
private String contactvalue;
private Long studentId;
i want to write method while creating new contact if person uses PHONENUMBER enum String contactvalue must be numbers only and if person uses EMAIL enum it can be characters too

Comment: Use validation (regex for example) . What is the issue?

Comment: private ContactType contacttype;
    @NotBlank(message = "ContactValue cannot be blank")
    @Length(min = 9, max = 20, message = "ContactValue must be between 9-20 characters")
    private String contactvalue;
    private Long studentId;
this is my ContactDTO

i want to write method to create new contact but if person uses PHONENUMBER enum then contactvalue must be numbers only (idk how to validate that) and person uses email it can be characters too

Comment: if i use regex then whole contactvalue becomes numbers only but i dont want to do that , then if person chooses email enum email becomes numbers too

Comment: When posting code _please_ format it so it's actually recognizable as code and readable for us mere humans. Putting at least that much effort into your question will make people much more willing to help.

Comment: As I see you can't use enum for ContactType it should be a class with fields email, phoneNumber  etc. And than you can validate every field you want.

Comment: Please, edit the question to make it valuable for other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a method that takes the enum and value and which checks the value based on the enum.

It could be as simple as this:

```
public void setContact(ContactType type, String value) {
  //check the value first
  switch(type) {
    case PHONENUMBER: {
      if( !StringUtils.isNumeric(value) ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("phone number must be numeric");
      }
      break;
    }
    case EMAIL: {
      //note: emails contain more than just numbers and alphabetic chars
      if( !StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(value) ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("email must be alphanumeric");
      }
      break;
    }
  }

   this.value = value;
}
```

However, you might need more types or more complex ones, so you could try to use regular expressions instead ("manually" crafted rules are faster for many simple cases but require a yet more complex design):

```
 enum ContactType {
   PHONENUMBER("\\d+"),
   EMAIL(/*pattern for email*/);

   Pattern pattern;

   private ContactType(String regex) {
     pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
   }

   public void validateInput(String input) {
     if(!pattern.matcher(input).matches()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input invalid");
     }
   }
 }
```

And setting the value:

```
 public void setContact(ContactType type, String value) {
   type.validateInput(value);

   this.value = value;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

ContactType should be a class with fields email, phoneNumber etc. And than you can validate every field you want.

Answer (score 0):

Really not much details in the questions. Since you tagged the question with "spring-boot", I suppose we're talking `(javax|jakarta).validation.` stuff? In this case you could use class-level validation.

Some snippets:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ContactTypeValidator.class)
public @interface ContactTypeValid {
 
    String message() default "contact value invalid for specified type";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
 
}
```

```
public class ContactTypeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ContactTypeValid, ContactDTO> {
 
    @Override
    public void initialize(ContactTypeValid constraint) {
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(ContactDTO contactDTO, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // put your logic here. e.g.
        
        // deal with possible nulls

        if(PHONENUMBER == contactDTO.getContacttype()) {
          return contactDTO.getContactvalue().chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
class MyController {

  @PostMapping("/api/contact")
  void postContact(@Valid ContactDTO contactDTO) {
    ...
  }
  

}
```

Annotate your ContactDTO:

```
@ContactTypeValid
public class ContactDTO {
  ...
}
```

You will also need validation implementation in your dependencies, like `spring-boot-starter-validation`.

Spring documentation for more: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#validation-beanvalidation

---

And good point from @Игорь-Ходыко. Use separate fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a digit validator:

```
  enum ContactEnum {EMAIL, PHONENUMBER}
      private boolean validatePhoneNumber(ContactEnum type, String contactString) {
    
        if (type == ContactEnum.PHONENUMBER) {
          return contactString.chars().filter(Character::isDigit).count() == contactString.length();
        }
        return false;
      }
```